# How to prove an inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I didn't know where can I start because it doesn't fit to any theories or formulas.

> If $a>0$, $b>0$, $c>0$ and $a+b+c=1$, prove that:
>
> $$\frac{a^3}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{b^3}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{c^3}{c^2+a^2}\geq \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @RobertZ, that post has no answers, so I'm not sure how that would help.

Comment: It fits into the Arithmetic Mean and geometric mean theorem.... probably.  Things dont have to fit into theorems and formulas to be true.  Math isn't about memorizing and plugging in values, it involves thought as well.

Comment: @fleablood actually the text needs 30 letters to completely submit. So I just write what ever in order to submit the problem. But thanks for advices.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that using AM-GM,
$$\frac{a^3}{a^2+b^2} = a - \frac{ab^2}{a^2+b^2} \geqslant a - \frac{ab^2}{2ab} = a - \frac{b}2 $$

Hence $$\sum_{cyc} \frac{a^3}{a^2+b^2} \geqslant \frac{a+b+c}2 = \frac12$$

Comment: I am totally understanding thank you so much:)

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{a^2+b^2}\geq\frac{1}{2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{a^2+b^2}\geq\frac{a+b+c}{2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^3}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{a}{2}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a(a^2-b^2)}{a^2+b^2}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a(a^2-b^2)}{a^2+b^2}-(a-b)\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{b(a-b)^2}{a^2+b^2}\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate it.